# R make a hole in a polygon for a ggplot mask

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm making a mask for a ggplot. How can I delete the area inside a circle drawn over a `ggplot` without using GIS procedures? I have a `data.frame` used to make a bounding box over a plot and a circle, as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
bndBox <- data.frame(x=c(-Inf,Inf,Inf,-Inf),
                     y=c(Inf,Inf,-Inf,-Inf),
                     id="bnd")

hole <- data.frame(
  x = cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 360)),
  y = sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 360)),
  id="circle"
)

porthole <- rbind(bndBox,hole)

ggplot() + 
  # I want to be able to see this point
  geom_point(aes(x = 0,y = 0)) +
  # But not this point
  geom_point(aes(x = -1,y = 0)) +
  geom_polygon(data=porthole, 
               aes(x = x, y = y, fill = id),
               inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image: output image: orange background with blue cirlce]

Comment: Place the call to `geom_point` after the call to `geom_polygon`. Or use `alpha` in your call to `geom_polygon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer to take into account that a closed polygon progressing clockwise forms a hole.

```r
library(ggplot2)

bndBox <- data.frame(x=c(-Inf,-Inf,Inf,Inf, -Inf),
                     y=c(-Inf,Inf,Inf,-Inf, -Inf),
                     id="bnd")

bndBox <- data.frame(x=c(-1,1,1,-1, -1),
                     y=c(-1,-1,1,1, -1),
                     id="bnd")

hole <- data.frame(
  x = cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 360)) * 0.95,
  y = sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 360)) * 0.95,
  id="circle"
)


porthole <- rbind(bndBox,hole)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=porthole, 
               aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "red")+
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = 0)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'd like the bnd to be opaque and the area inside the circle to be transparent.

Comment: See update for a better approach.

Comment: Ah. Yep. Had to close the polygon like with sf below. Thanks!

Comment: Slightly neater version added; interesting alternative you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I can do what I want with `sf` but was hoping not to go down this road as I find the code hard to follow and feel like geom_polygon() should be able to handle it. Here is a cumbersome solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

bndBox <- data.frame(x=c(-1,1,1,-1),
                     y=c(1,1,-1,-1),
                     id="bnd")
hole <- data.frame(
  x = cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 360)),
  y = sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 360)),
  id="circle"
)


portholeSF <- st_sfc(
  st_polygon(
    list(
      hole = cbind(
        c(hole$x,hole$x[1]), 
        c(hole$y,hole$y[1])
      ),
      bnd = cbind(
        c(bndBox$x,bndBox$x[1]), 
        c(bndBox$y,bndBox$y[1])
      )
    )
  )
)

ggplot() + 
  # I want to see this point
  geom_point(aes(x = 0,y = 0)) +
  # But not this point
  geom_point(aes(x = -0.75,y = 0.75)) +
  geom_sf(data = portholeSF)
```